# Flat modules and non-vanishing of simple tensors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a noncommutative ring, and $M$ and $N$ be a right and a left $R$-module respectively. If $M$ or $N$ is projective, then 
$$
0 \neq m \otimes n  \in M \otimes_R N, ~~~ \textrm{for all } n \in N, m \in M.
$$
Is this true is $M$ or $N$ are flat, or torsion free.

Comment: $M$ and $N$ should be right and left respectively and $R$ should be $B$?

Comment: Flat is not enough : with $R=\mathbb{Z}, M=\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ and $N=\mathbb{Z}/2$. You have $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}N=0$. (Of course my example is commutative, but you can tensor it with any noncommutative algebra).

Comment: Flat: no, I don't think so: let $R=k[x]/(x^2)$ and $M=N=R$ and $m=n=x$.